# How to take the rows that are related to same item but in different dates and create columns with the values from the first and last date, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table:

| Ticker | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2020-04-01 | 10 |
| MSFT | 2020-04-01 | 20 |
| MSFT | 2021-01-01 | 10 |
| Apple | 2021-01-01 | 5 |
| Apple | 2021-04-01 | 30 |
| MSFT | 2021-04-01 | 50 |

And I want to transform to this:

| Ticker | Price_of_the_first_observation | Price_of_the_second_observation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 30 |
| MSFT | 20 | 50 |

Comment: If the name of the second column `Price_of_the_second_observation` or should it be `Price_of_the_last_observation`?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already sorted by Date:

```
df.groupby('Ticker')['Price'].agg(Price_of_the_first_observation='first',
                                  Price_of_the_last_observation='last')
```

OR if the name of the second columns should be `Price_of_the_last_observation`:

```
(df.groupby('Ticker')['Price']
   .agg(['first', 'last'])
   .add_prefix('Price_of_the_')
   .add_suffix('_observation')
)
```

output:

```
        Price_of_the_first_observation  Price_of_the_last_observation
Ticker                                                               
Apple                               10                             30
MSFT                                20                             50
```

To sort your values:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

#### edit: for all the values:

```
(df.assign(group=df.groupby('Ticker').cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index='Ticker', columns='group', values='Price')
   .add_prefix('Price_of_the_#')
)
```

output:

```
group   Price_of_the_#1  Price_of_the_#2  Price_of_the_#3
Ticker                                                   
Apple                10                5               30
MSFT                 20               10               50
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to select the price of the date in between the first and last dates too?

Comment: can you give an example of the output?

Comment: check the update

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted.